# Handling prisma migration inside a dockerized dev environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, database-migration, prisma

I'm working on a Express API and using Prisma to communicate with a Postgres database. I want to create a dockerized development environment, and so far i have a working solution but its not ideal. I was told that opening a port on the database container could be a security concern. But because of this i can only run the migration command inside the app container. It might be just a minor inconvinience, but i feel like there must be a better solution out there.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:20-alpine as development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json .

COPY prisma ./prisma/

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM node:20-alpine as production

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install --only=production

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

RUN ["node", "dist/index.js"]
```

And my docker-compose.dev.yml file is the following:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    command: npm run dev

  postgres:
    image: postgres:16
    ...

  redis:
    image: redis

volumes:
  postgres:
```

Mabye i should just open the postgres container in the docker-compose.dev.yml? Or maybe there is a way to run migration automatically when the prisma/schema.prisma file changes? And if it can be done, should it be done?

I would appriciate some feedback. Im new to docker, prisma and the idea of migrations.